# Integration of Augmented reality app into Phone gap or cordova or Android studio

Tags: cordova, vuforia

I have already developed an Android and iOS application using Phonegap and Cordova. Now that I need to add an Augmented reality scanning option under one button in an activity, how do I proceed.

I tried developing the Augmented reality scene using Unity and Vuforia, but now I have two separate apk's and want to know how to integrate the Unity scene into the app using Phonegap or Cordova or Android studio.

That is, the augmented reality scene from unity and scanning (Apk 2) should only start when I click on a button from my main activity (Apk 1).

Answer (score 1):

I've created a Vuforia Cordova plugin that might be of help?

https://github.com/thisisbd/cordova-plugin-vuforia

The plugin itself is designed to work with Cordova 5.* and has a comprehensive README.

We've used it in the past on commercial applications for Peugeot along with many others.

It adds the Vuforia library into your cordova application and allows you to recognise images from the camera.

In our applications we have a 'Brochure interaction' button in the bottom right:
[image: Peugeot 208 application screen shot]

When you click this button you can scan a page of the 208 brocure and be given additional information within the app.

At the moment it supports scanning for, and recognising, image. We pass the image ID to your cordova application where you can then process it.

You can see the (UK) Peugeot app [here](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/new-peugeot-208/id1020630968?mt=8). We happily answer issues and pull requests on the GitHub page if you get stuck!